# Javascript number regex test failing - can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's a jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUpyd/)

Relevant code:

```
var number = /\d+(.\d+)?/g;

$('body').append(number.test(2.5) + "<br>");
$('body').append(number.test(20) + "<br>");
$('body').append(number.test(2) + "<br>");
```

Output

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: You should probably escape the period, eg `\.`. `.` on its own is a wildcard match

Comment: @Phil - Not related, but **true indeed** ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUpyd/2/)).

Comment: @jahroy It's not the problem here but it would result in more false positives such as `2af`

Comment: @Phil - I'm agreeing with you.  I updated the fiddle to demonstrate your point ;-)

Comment: Actually... Phil's point is **very important**.  Most strings that begin with a number will pass the above test.  For example: 2blahblahblah would pass!!!! ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUpyd/5/)).

Comment: Oh wow, for some reason I thought you didn't have to escape it in a group but that makes no sense. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the `g`.  It's not needed, and it causes the regex to fail because the RegExp object keeps track of its position based on the previous match: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

http://jsfiddle.net/BUpyd/1/